# does TCP/IP Async Server/Client Receive Data Separately?

Tags: c#, tcp

i always appreciate you guys for helping me.

today's question is,

i'm creating communication program dealing with both TCP and Serial(UART)

I know Because Serial Communication is Asynchronous Communication,
so, sometimes Communication Data from another node can be split.

```
for example)
Sender's full packet : 
0x00 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x06 0x07

but, Receiver's packet (it can be split often like this):
0x00 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05
0x06 0x07
```

however, **in TCP Asynchronous Client/Server (Non Blocking Type)
also can occur the same phenomenon ??** <- this is my Question.

or, always can they receive full packet without separation??

this is a part of my source code. (C# UWP)

```
using System.Net.Sockets;
```

...

```
    private Socket m_ServerSocket;
    private List<Socket> m_ClientSocket;
```

...

```
            m_ServerSocket = new Socket(
                                AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                                SocketType.Stream,
                                ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, m_iPort);
            m_ServerSocket.Bind(ipep);
            m_ServerSocket.Listen(m_iClientsLimit);

            SocketAsyncEventArgs args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            args.Completed
                += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(Accept_Completed);
            m_ServerSocket.AcceptAsync(args);
```

...

```
            byte[] m_szData = new byte[m_iBufferSize];
            args.SetBuffer(m_szData, 0, m_iBufferSize);
            args.UserToken = m_ClientSocket;
            args.Completed
                += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(Receive_Completed);
            bool bResult = ClientSocket.ReceiveAsync(args);
```

thank you for reading my question.

Comment: TCP is **not** a message based protocol. It accumulates data into internal buffers, then splits the stream into segments and ignores boundaries between sends. If you are lucky receiver will get the same chunks, as you send. But there is no guarantee. If you need to send messages, then you have to define message structure and reassemble messages at receiver.

Comment: Both TCP and Serial Port handle receive data should be handled exactly the same.  Data comes in chunks so your receive has to be able to wait until the entire message is received.   So normally you use one of three methods 1) Ascii : Use a character not in the message like a return to terminate each message 2) Ascii or Binary : Add a count at beginning of  each message to determine end of message 3)Ascii or Binary : Message has fixed length.

Comment: You define the send/receive buffer size. So if you see that your messages come in different parts, like you mentioned, then you're using different buffer size for send and receive

Comment: Mrg Gek// so, if i set sufficient buffer size, can i always get full packet without separation??